# Return Top Three Occurring Strings from the Results of a Select Statement

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a table with three columns. The first column is a PK. The second column contains 5 distinct URLs (the URLs are steps in a process, one URL represents step #1, etc). The third column contains User-Agent strings.

```
SELECT * FROM UserAgent WHERE URL LIKE '%Step2%' ORDER BY UserAgentString;
```

I want to return the top three User-Agent strings based on the number of times they occur in a particular step. How would I do that?

If there's better way to query the desired result set, I'm up for any suggestions.

Comment: It's a varchar.

Comment: Tip: It's helpful to tag database questions with both the appropriate software (MySQL, Oracle, DB2, ...) and version, e.g. `sql-server-2014`. Differences in syntax and features often affect the answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this**

```
WITH CTE AS(
       SELECT Col1,Col2,Col3,LEN(Col2)-LEN(REPLACE(Col2,Col3,'')) Occurance 
       FROM UserAgent  
)
SELECT TOP (3) Col1,Col2,Col3
FROM CTE
ORDER BY Occurance
```

Comment: 'WITH CTE AS(...)' is that creating a temp table?

Comment: No it is not create temporary table it just temparay result set

Comment: "CTE" = Common Table Expression (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

What JayDipJ posted is efficient but will only work if the length of col3 is 1. Have a look at this sample code:

```
-- Sample data:
DECLARE @userAgent TABLE (col2 varchar(100), url varchar(100));
INSERT @userAgent VALUES 
('dog','this dog, that dog... Dogs?'),
('cat','cats, cats, cats and more cats'),
('bird', 'bird, bird!'),
('xxx', 'xxx yyy zzz');

-- solution:
SELECT TOP (3) *, Occurances = (LEN(url) - LEN(REPLACE(url,col2,''))) / LEN(col2)
FROM @userAgent
ORDER BY (LEN(url) - LEN(REPLACE(url,col2,''))) / LEN(col2) DESC;
```

The thing to note, however, is that this method will fail if there is any overlapping values. For example the string ".." appears four times here: "... ..."; the above method would return a wrong answer. In cases where there could be overlap I would use Ngrams8K (http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/142316/). The NGrams8K solution would look like this:

```
-- sample data with overlapping values:
DECLARE @userAgent TABLE (col2 varchar(100), url varchar(100));
INSERT @userAgent VALUES ('..', 'blah... blah...'), ('!!', 'Fantastic!!!'),('xx','abc');

-- solution:
SELECT url, Occurances = COUNT(*)
FROM @userAgent
CROSS APPLY dbo.NGrams8k(url, LEN(col2))
WHERE token = col2
GROUP BY ALL url;
```

Results:

```
url               Occurances
----------------- -----------
abc               0
blah... blah...   4
Fantastic!!!      2
```